# Using PayPal Payflow, American Express cards keep getting declined with error 10576

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Recently I noticed that our online shopping cart (which uses Payflow) is failing for most customers using an American Express card, with error 10576. The response text is "A customer service phone number is required to process transactions. Please add a customer service phone number to your PayPal account or contact PayPal for more info." PayPal's help documentation provides no information about how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what it says: it needs a customer service phone number because American Express has recently become more stringent about requiring it -- they just don't document how to do this, and it's a little unintuitive. It has to be attached to your *normal* PayPal account, not via the PayPal Manager interface. The steps to follow are below:

1. Identify which PayPal account is associated with your Paypal Manager account by logging into Manager and visiting this page: https://manager.paypal.com/processorInfo.do
2. Log into that PayPal account, then in the top right corner hover over your account name and choose "Account Settings". [image: Screenshot of account menu for PayPal]
3. In the sidebar menu on the Settings page, choose "Business Information" and then click Update. [image: Screenshot of relevant menu options]
4. You will see your business information page. Click Edit in the top section. [image: Screenshot of business profile page with relevant link highlighted]
5. Add your customer service phone number in the form that comes up and Save the resulting info.

This should resolve the error!